# Why can't std::make_unique deduce the type of brace-initialized parameters?

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-functions, perfect-forwarding, list-initialization

Consider the following code snippet

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int x, y;
};

struct B{
    A a;

    B(A a): a(a) {}
};

int main() {
    // Ok
    B({2,3});

    // Ok
    auto ptr = new B({2,3});

    // Ok
    auto ptr_2 = std::make_unique<B>(A{2, 3});

    // Error
    auto ptr_3 = std::make_unique<B>({2, 3});
}
```

When initializing a `B` object in the first two ways, one can create a temporary `A` constructor parameter without naming the type and the compiler can figure out what it represents and what constructor it should call.

However, `std::make_unique` fails to compile without explicitly naming the type of the parameter. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), the function call is equivalent to

```cpp
unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

I had expected the call with `std::forward` to be equivalent to `new B({2,3});`, but that is not the case on the compilers I tested, namely gcc and clang trunk. Are they wrong? If not, why does forwarding the arguments not work as I expected?

Comment: `{2, 3}` has no type, so template deduction fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is how C++ works (or doesn't work, in the eye of the beholder). As you've correctly pointed out, this construct uses universal references, which cannot bind to type-less braced initialization lists. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So it is the `std::forward` call itself that fails and it has nothing to do with the constructor? Still, could it not be forwarded as an initializer list or some special type which could then be used at the call site if appropriate?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the constructor.